# Loop through ag-grid data and display values

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

I am looping through each node of ag-grid data and have to display column values.Attached is the plunkr:
https://plnkr.co/edit/cFBLm7DkAZL5oWbqdyub?p=preview.

I am not able to display the ag-grid data in the console.

```
var gridOptions = {
defaultColDef: {
    sortable: true
},
columnDefs: columnDefs,
animateRows: true,
enableRangeSelection: true,
rowData: rowData,
checkbox : true,
onSelectionChanged : getData
};
   new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);
});

function getData(){
  gridOptions.api.forEachNode( function (node) {
   console.log("node vaalues are:"+node.data);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple things wrong with your code.

1. Inorder for `onSelectChanged` to be called you need to specify how you want row selection to work, try: `rowSelection: 'single'`
2. In your plunkr (not your snippet above), your `getData` function is in the wrong scope.  By this I mean all of your code is inside the `document.addEventListener`, but the `getData` is not.  Because of this, `getData` doesn't know what `gridOptions` is.

Updated plunkr: https://next.plnkr.co/edit/cXKVZrT9siHoodVa